# Field lines of vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

Okey if $\phi(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2), (x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Find the field lines for $\mathbf{G}=\nabla \phi$.

So $\mathbf{G}=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{i}+\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{j}$ right? To find the field lines we use:

$$\begin{align} \frac{dx}{\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}}&=\frac{dy}{\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}}, \bigg|\times \frac{2}{x^2+y^2} \\
\frac{dx}{x}&=\frac{dy}{y} \\
\log|Ax|&=\log|y|\\
y&=Ax\end{align} $$

So the field lines are lines thru origo? When graphing the lines how does I know the magnitude of the lines? (the graph with small arrows)

Comment: More geometrically, the level sets $\phi(x,y) = c $ are all circles centered at the origin, so the gradient vectors will be perpendicular to those circles.  These all point along lines out of the origin, so the field lines are lines through the origin.

Comment: I'm not a visual person and just started playing around with vector fields. The systematic way I found out that the field lines are lines trough origo is still correct? How did you figure out the lengt of the field lines?

Comment: The field lines are just lines, as far as I am aware. They wouldn't have a length.  Your analysis looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it directly from the formula.
$$G(x,y) = \frac{2}{|(x,y)|^2}(x,y)  = \frac{2}{r^2}(x,y)$$
(where $r$ is the magnitude of $(x,y)$) so the field vector at $(x,y)$ points in the same direction as the radius vector to the point, *i.e.,* directly away from the origin at all points $\neq (0,0)$. You can see the magnitude of the field vector at $(x,y)$ is $\frac2r$ as well.

Comment: My books answer says that the field lines are "half-lines" (I don't know the correct word) meaning they don't have beginning. And that they start from origo.. True?

Comment: meaning... what makes them start from origo and not go trough all R

Comment: @ELEC: Note that $\phi$, and $G$, are not defined at the origin (the domain is "punctured" there). So, yes, they are open rays emanating in all directions from the origin.

Comment: Oh yeah! makes sense! THANKS!